# Может ли конретный символ убивать GET запрос? Или как "Игорь" все сломал =)

Tags: php, get, request

Случился очень веселый глюк. Передаю в GET запросах имя и секретный ключ.

Часть имен не загрузились по причине провала ключа. Проверил массив `$_GET`, а он пустой. В итоге потестил и пришел к следующему:

если в GET запросе посылать кириллическую букву "р", то есть символ → `%D1%80`
то в массиве `$_GET` пусто. и если убираю ее оттуда, то все ок.
`%D1%79` и `%D1%81` тоже работают..

в `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` при этом вся строка присутствует:

```
/cllbck/?s=afa2gfdrfd&id=34&first_name=%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C
```

попробовал разные варианты имени
Появляется в определенных комбинациях, например:
Игор или Игорь - не работает, а
Игр - работает. Тимур не работает)) в общем треш.

Подскажите пожалуйста хоть в какую сторону копать чтобы получить все-таки нормальный набор параметров.

Answer (score 1):

я пока только такой костыль для себя нашел:

```
$q = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['query'];
parse_str($q, $get);
print_r($get);
```